# Trying to plot SQL datetime data in PyQt5 GUI

Tags: python, mysql, matplotlib, pyqt5

I'm creating a simple GUI with a visualization feature. I'm querying a database to get the data I need which I in turn then want to plot and show in my GUI.

The code for the query and plot is below:

```
class Sheet(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setUpCanvasUi()
        self.connectSignalSlots()
        
    
    def setUpCanvasUi(self):
        self.sc = myCanvas()
        self.l=QVBoxLayout(self.ui.frame)
        self.l.addWidget(self.sc)
        self.ui.centralwidget.setLayout(self.l)
        
    def connectSignalSlots(self):
        
        self.ui.actionShow_Plot.triggered.connect(self.Plot)
    
    def db_plot_values(self):
        self.mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
                            user="root",
                            password="*********",
                            database="allocation")
        self.mycursor = self.mydb.cursor()

        # Fecthing Data From mysql to my python progam
        self.mycursor.execute("select date, net_data from table1 where point = '5'")
        self.result = self.mycursor.fetchall

        date = []
        net_data = []

        for i in self.mycursor:
            date.append(i[0])
            net_data.append(i[1])
        
        self.x = date
        self.y = net_data
        
        
        

    def Plot(self):
        
        self.sc.plot(self.x,self.y)
    

class myCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):    
        self.fig = Figure()
        
        super(myCanvas,self).__init__(self.fig,*args,**kwargs)
    
    def plot(self,x,y):
        self.fig.clear()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax.plot(x[1:],y[1:])
        self.draw()
```

The error I get here is TypeError: `'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable`

I have tried removing the square brackets in the `def plot()`  function but it still does not work.

I think this is because my date data is in datatime like `[datetime.date(2021, 3, 1), datetime.date(2021, 3, 2), datetime.date(2021, 3, 3), datetime.date(2021, 3, 4), datetime.date(2021, 3, 5), datetime.date(2021, 3, 6), datetime.date(2021, 3, 7)]` while the net_data is in decimal. But I have no idea how to fix it.

The rest of the code is just the layout gotten from QtDesigner, that's why it isn't pasted.

Comment: TYPOs: change to `self.result = self.mycursor.fetchall()`and  `for i in self.result:`

Comment: I did that but I till got `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable`